# Significato dell'espressione "rigetto di pancia"

Tags: word-usage, meaning

In una discussione recente nella stanza di chat [Bar Sport](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11367/bar-sport) è apparsa l'espressione "rigetto di pancia", che non conoscevo.

Cercandola in rete, ho visto che viene usata in alcuni siti web e anche su [questo libro](https://books.google.es/books?id=QuZjAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT53&lpg=PT53&dq=%22rigetto+di+pancia%22&source=bl&ots=Jbn5-7_ZCi&sig=ACfU3U3CCZrEe4fIdNI-p2qQ9-wqGEoAPQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjL7tvw2vziAhVYBWMBHYZcBGMQ6AEwAXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22rigetto%20di%20pancia%22&f=false).

Per cercare di capirne il senso, ho letto il contenuto della voce "pancia" che si trova alle pagine [457](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI12/GDLI_12_ocr_464.pdf), [458](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI12/GDLI_12_ocr_465.pdf) e [459](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI12/GDLI_12_ocr_466.pdf) del volume XII del *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana* (ho scelto questo dizionario perché ho scoperto recentemente che molti dei vocaboli e espressioni che prima non trovavo su altri dizionari qui vengono riportati).

Ho cercato anche ["rigetto"](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI16/GDLI_16_ocr_324.pdf) su questo stesso dizionario e ho visto che può significare "rifiuto".

Tuttavia, non riesco a vedere qual è il significato di "rigetto di pancia". Me lo sapreste spiegare? Potreste anche fare qualche esempio di uso di questa espressione?

Comment: È sostanzialmente un rifiuto d’istinto, senza ragionare, senza riflettere. Ad esempio l’espressione, _parlare alla pancia della gente_, molto di attualità in questo periodo politico in Italia, significa stuzzicare gli impulsi, le emozioni  più profonde delle persone.

Comment: Mi piacerebbe sapere qual è la ragione del voto negativo. Forse il problema è che si tratta di un'espressione che veramente non si usa in italiano se non come calco dell'inglese "gut"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

È sostanzialmente un rifiuto d’istinto, senza ragionare, senza riflettere.

Ad esempio l’espressione, *parlare alla pancia della gente*, molto di attualità in questo periodo politico in Italia, significa stuzzicare gli impulsi, le emozioni più profonde delle persone.

In [un articolo del *Corriere della Sera*](https://www.google.com/amp/www.corriere.it/moda/news/17_agosto_18/decidere-pancia-non-pentirsene-quando-l-istinto-che-insegna-131c5bec-842a-11e7-b6d5-ef8089a81d10_amp.html) viene riportato cosa significa l’eseguire un’azione di pancia.

> «Di regola le grandi decisioni della vita umana hanno a che fare più
>   con gli istinti che con la volontà cosciente e la ragionevolezza»,
>   sostiene lo psicoanalista e sociologo Erich Fromm.

Comment: Trovo interessante leggere l'articolo completo per capire meglio il significato dell'espressione.

Comment: Quindi, in generale "pancia" è usato in modo molto simile all'inglese  ["gut"](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/gut): «Used in reference to a feeling or reaction based on an instinctive emotional response rather than considered thought.» Per esempio: «I had a gut feeling that something was wrong» (molti altri esempi vengono riportati nel link che ho messo).

Comment: La cosa curiosa è che questa definizione si trovi sui dizionari inglesi, ma non sui dizionari italiani.